# My SSD runs extremely slow

Tags: ssd, storage

I've bought a Toshiba SSD, model: Z1000001. It works, but is really, really slow.

- AHCI is enabled
- TRIM is enabled
- BIOS has been updated
- SATA cables and ports tested (SATA II0)
- I've been through all tips I could find from Google but still nothing.

It has 25-94 MB/s read and 24 MB/s write. It varies.

Specifications:

- CPU: Intel Core2 Quad Q6600
- mobo: Fujitsu Siemens Scaleo H P35B - FB
- RAM: 6GB
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GT630
- SSD: 64 Toshiba / 500GB WD

Comment: Do you know if your SATA ports are version 1,2,or 3?

Comment: It's 2.0 sata ports

Comment: Sata 2.0 is 300 MB/s and Sata 3.0 is 600 MB/s. Your Sata connection is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Eraser
http://eraser.heidi.ie/

to zero just the free space.

Comment: How will this help the OP's problem?

Comment: Sometimes zeroing the free space will restore performance.  I have done this my self with an SSD and it really works.